# Is it safe to slice stateless derived classes?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class that contains some data:

```
struct Base
{
  int a,b,c,d;
};
```

Many derived classes are defined to represent different types of generation and manipulation of `Base`, eg.:

```
struct AlphaA : public Base
{
  AlphaA():a(2),b(0),c(0),d(1){;}
};

struct AlphaB : public Base
{
  AlphaB():a(2),b(1),c(0),d(1)
    {complex_function(*this);}
};
 // ...many more
```

After generating and processing any derived object, the states of `a,b,c,d` are sufficient to fully represent the intended object.

Now I need a function to process a `vector` of Base:

```
void processB (std::vector<Base> & bs);
```

Normally, with more complex derived classes, I would pass the argument as a vector of `std::unique_poiner<Base>` but, in this case, the derived classes have no members and they act only as a *temporary type safe interface*, and the original type of the derived class will never again be needed, so I'm willing to just slice the derived objects into a vector, as in:

```
AlphaA B1;
AlphaB B2;
AlphaA B3;
some_function(B3);
// (...)
std::vector<Base> Bs{B1, B2, B3};
processB(Bs);
```

Is it safe to slice the objects in this case? I'm willing to know this before considering alternative solutions and patterns.

(Specifically, I want the derived cases to be of different types for some stages of the algorithm before decaying then to `Base`, so I'm ruling out a generator function of `Base` that accepts a type flag or something like that.)

Comment: Slicing objects is typically safe in general. The problem with slicing is that sometimes people don't realize that they are slicing and think they're doing something else.

Comment: If the only difference is the code you use to initialize the objects is why not make factories?  You could have `Base make_alpha(args); Base make_beta(args); ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by *safe* here. Slicing is always safe - as in, it doesn't incur UB. Whether it is what you need or not is totally up to you.

Having said that, I would not use inheritance to solve the problem. Rather I'd have classes with static members to manipulate the argument in the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing is not inherently dangerous. It does not invite undefined behaviour in and of itself (note that the compiler will stop you from creating an instance of an abstract class). It's safe to slice objects *when you know what you're doing.*

Comment: Guess I've heard so much of "avoid slicing" that I started to doubt myself.

Comment: @Kahler that's because slicing is very seldom a solution (and I do not think it is a solution in your case as well). If you do not need an object, just don't make one.

Comment: @SergeyA I understand your point and can see the good advice. My doubt was just about the safety of slicing a stateless derived class.

Comment: @Kahler • Brian's "when you know what you're doing" is the tricky part.  Not perhaps for you, but amongst developers in general.  So since you appear to be cautious yet cognizant of the caveats, my only recommendation is to comment the code well, so the developer after you can figure out what and why the code needs to be treated carefully.

Answer (score 1):

> but, in this case, the derived classes have no members and they act only as a temporary type safe interface, and the original type of the derived class will never again be needed,

Make sure that is true, doubly, triply. In general, this is rarely true. There is a reason why you create objects of derived types and the same reasons will lead you down the path where you will want to know the derived type of the objects.

However, if after making doubly and triply sure that you don't need the derived type, then there are no risks in slicing the derived type objects to base type objects.